# Jackson "InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id" when deserializing class with @JsonTypeInfo annotation from Avro file

Tags: java, jackson, avro

I'm stuck trying to understand how `jackson-dataformat-avro` resolves type IDs. I have serialized a class successfully and now try to deserialize it again, with the same schema. It has a private field `"name"` of type `LocalizedString`. But I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'org.example.LocalizedString' as a subtype of [simple type, class org.example.LocalizedString]: known type ids = [LocalizedString] (for POJO property 'name')
```

The `LocalizedString` class looks like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property="type")
@Value
public class LocalizedString {

    private Map<Language, String> strings;

    ...
}
```

In the Avro schema file, I typed the `name` field as follows:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "type": {
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "org.example",
    "name": "LocalizedString",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "type",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "strings",
        "type": ["null", {
          "type": "map",
          "values": "string"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I leave out the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation, then it works. However, I'm using it for Json serialization elsewhere, so I'd love to keep it.

What is the specific problem for Avro here?

And maybe it's also problematic that the key of the `strings` map is not a string?

Comment: Removing the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation and instead adding `type` as a final field solves this issue. Although it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: I had to solve in the same way (with POJO), but I don't like this way. Have you another solution?

Comment: No, I never looked deeper into this...